# Error: Cannot find module 'nanoid/non-secure'

Tags: vuejs2, postcss

My project was building up until today.  I did not change anything just to be clear.  Oddly enough, it is also happening on another NPM project that I had not touched in weeks.

I'm getting the following error (see below).  I tried deleting my node_modules and running "npm install" afterwards.  It appears that certain libraries are directly referencing "nanoid/non-secure" yet NPM is not installing it.  When I install "nanoid" as a devDependency, I get a whole host of other errors.

===============PACKAGE.JSON===================================

```
{
    "name": "sysifix.vue-ui",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "Sysifix.VueUI",
    "private": true,
    "author": {
        "name": "Rivera, Rashad"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --copy",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build --mode production",
        "build_dev": "vue-cli-service build --mode development",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint --no-fix",
        "lint_fix": "vue-cli-service lint",
        "clean": "",
        "test": "jest",
        "test_watch": "jest --watchAll"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "~0.21.1",
        "core-js": "~3.6.5",
        "moment": "~2.29.0",
        "name-of": "~1.0.2",
        "vue": "~2.6.12",
        "vue-class-component": "~7.2.6",
        "vue-property-decorator": "~9.0.0",
        "vue-router": "~3.4.5",
        "vue-the-mask": "~0.11.1",
        "vue-unique-id": "~3.1.1",
        "vuedraggable": "~2.24.3",
        "vuetify": "~2.3.12",
        "vuetify-confirm": "~2.0.6",
        "vuex": "~3.5.1",
        "vuex-class": "~0.3.2",
        "vuex-router-sync": "~5.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "~5.15.0",
        "@types/jest": "~26.0.14",
        "@types/vue-the-mask": "~0.11.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~4.3.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~4.3.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.6",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.6",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.6",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.6",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.6",
        "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "~5.1.0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "~5.1.0",
        "@vue/test-utils": "~1.1.0",
        "babel-core": "~7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-jest": "~26.6.3",
        "eslint": "~7.10.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "~7.0.0",
        "jest": "~26.5.3",
        "jest-transform-stub": "~2.0.0",
        "sass": "~1.26.11",
        "sass-loader": "~10.0.2",
        "ts-jest": "~26.4.1",
        "ts-nameof": "~5.0.0",
        "typescript": "~4.0.3",
        "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.0.7",
        "vue-jest": "~3.0.7",
        "vue-template-compiler": "~2.6.12",
        "vuetify-loader": "~1.7.1"
    },
    "resolutions": {},
    "postcss": {
        "plugins": {
            "autoprefixer": {}
        }
    }
}
```

===============VUE.CONFIG.JSON================================

```
/* eslint-disable */
module.exports = {

  publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL,
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],
  devServer: {

    compress: true,

    proxy: {
      '^/ui/api': {
        pathRewrite: { '^/ui/api': '/api' },
        target: process.env.VUE_APP_DEV_API_URL,
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rule('vue').uses.delete('cache-loader');
    config.module.rule('js').uses.delete('cache-loader');
    config.module.rule('tsx').uses.delete('cache-loader');
    config.module.rule('ts').uses.delete('cache-loader');
  },
  parallel: true,
};
```

===============ERROR===================================

```
C:\Temp>npm install
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@2.2.1: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0: 3.x is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.

added 1928 packages, and audited 1929 packages in 20s

100 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

C:\Temp>npm run serve

> sysifix.vue-ui@0.0.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve --copy

 INFO  Starting development server...
 ERROR  Error: Cannot find module 'nanoid/non-secure'
Require stack:
- C:\Temp\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\@vue\component-compiler-utils\dist\compileStyle.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\@vue\component-compiler-utils\dist\index.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\index.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\config\base.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js
Error: Cannot find module 'nanoid/non-secure'
Require stack:
- C:\Temp\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\@vue\component-compiler-utils\dist\compileStyle.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\@vue\component-compiler-utils\dist\index.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\index.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\config\base.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js
- C:\Temp\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Temp\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:6:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Temp\node_modules\postcss\lib\parse.js:5:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
```

```
C:\Temp>npm ls --depth=1
sysifix.vue-ui@0.0.0 C:\Temp
+-- @fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.0
+-- @types/jest@26.0.14
| +-- jest-diff@25.5.0
| `-- pretty-format@25.5.0
+-- @types/vue-the-mask@0.11.1
| `-- vue@2.6.12 deduped
+-- @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@4.3.0
| +-- @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@4.3.0
| +-- @typescript-eslint/parser@4.3.0 deduped
| +-- @typescript-eslint/scope-manager@4.3.0
| +-- debug@4.3.1
| +-- eslint@7.10.0 deduped
| +-- functional-red-black-tree@1.0.1
| +-- regexpp@3.1.0
| +-- semver@7.3.5
| `-- tsutils@3.21.0
+-- @typescript-eslint/parser@4.3.0
| +-- @typescript-eslint/scope-manager@4.3.0 deduped
| +-- @typescript-eslint/types@4.3.0
| +-- @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@4.3.0
| +-- debug@4.3.1 deduped
| `-- eslint@7.10.0 deduped
+-- @vue/cli-plugin-babel@4.5.6
| +-- @babel/core@7.13.15
| +-- @vue/babel-preset-app@4.5.12
| +-- @vue/cli-service@4.5.6 deduped
| +-- @vue/cli-shared-utils@4.5.12
| +-- babel-loader@8.2.2
| +-- cache-loader@4.1.0
| +-- thread-loader@2.1.3
| `-- webpack@4.46.0
+-- @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.6
| +-- @vue/cli-service@4.5.6 deduped
| +-- @vue/cli-shared-utils@4.5.12 deduped
| +-- eslint-loader@2.2.1
| +-- eslint@7.10.0 deduped
| +-- globby@9.2.0
| +-- inquirer@7.3.3
| +-- webpack@4.46.0 deduped
| `-- yorkie@2.0.0
+-- @vue/cli-plugin-router@4.5.6
| +-- @vue/cli-service@4.5.6 deduped
| `-- @vue/cli-shared-utils@4.5.12 deduped
+-- @vue/cli-plugin-typescript@4.5.6
| +-- @types/webpack-env@1.16.0
| +-- @vue/cli-service@4.5.6 deduped
| +-- @vue/cli-shared-utils@4.5.12 deduped
| +-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY @vue/compiler-sfc@^3.0.0-beta.14
| +-- cache-loader@4.1.0 deduped
| +-- fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-v5@npm:fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@5.2.1
| +-- fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@3.1.1
| +-- globby@9.2.0
| +-- thread-loader@2.1.3 deduped
| +-- ts-loader@6.2.2
| +-- tslint@5.20.1
| +-- typescript@4.0.3 deduped
| +-- webpack@4.46.0 deduped
| `-- yorkie@2.0.0 deduped
+-- @vue/cli-service@4.5.6
| +-- @intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin@1.0.6
| +-- @soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@1.8.0
| +-- @soda/get-current-script@1.0.2
| +-- @types/minimist@1.2.1
| +-- @types/webpack-dev-server@3.11.3
| +-- @types/webpack@4.41.27
| +-- @vue/cli-overlay@4.5.12
| +-- @vue/cli-plugin-router@4.5.6 deduped
| +-- @vue/cli-plugin-vuex@4.5.12
| +-- @vue/cli-shared-utils@4.5.12 deduped
| +-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY @vue/compiler-sfc@^3.0.0-beta.14
| +-- @vue/component-compiler-utils@3.2.0
| +-- @vue/preload-webpack-plugin@1.1.2
| +-- @vue/web-component-wrapper@1.3.0
| +-- acorn-walk@7.2.0
| +-- acorn@7.4.1
| +-- address@1.1.2
| +-- autoprefixer@9.8.6
| +-- browserslist@4.16.4
| +-- cache-loader@4.1.0 deduped
| +-- case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin@2.4.0
| +-- cli-highlight@2.1.11
| +-- clipboardy@2.3.0
| +-- cliui@6.0.0
| +-- copy-webpack-plugin@5.1.2
| +-- css-loader@3.6.0
| +-- cssnano@4.1.11
| +-- debug@4.3.1 deduped
| +-- default-gateway@5.0.5
| +-- dotenv-expand@5.1.0
| +-- dotenv@8.2.0
| +-- file-loader@4.3.0
| +-- fs-extra@7.0.1
| +-- globby@9.2.0
| +-- hash-sum@2.0.0
| +-- html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0
| +-- launch-editor-middleware@2.2.1
| +-- lodash.defaultsdeep@4.6.1
| +-- lodash.mapvalues@4.6.0
| +-- lodash.transform@4.6.0
| +-- mini-css-extract-plugin@0.9.0
| +-- minimist@1.2.5
| +-- pnp-webpack-plugin@1.6.4
| +-- portfinder@1.0.28
| +-- postcss-loader@3.0.0
| +-- ssri@~6.0.2 invalid
| +-- terser-webpack-plugin@2.3.8
| +-- thread-loader@2.1.3 deduped
| +-- url-loader@2.3.0
| +-- vue-loader-v16@npm:vue-loader@16.2.0
| +-- vue-loader@15.9.6
| +-- vue-style-loader@4.1.3
| +-- vue-template-compiler@2.6.12 deduped
| +-- webpack-bundle-analyzer@3.9.0
| +-- webpack-chain@6.5.1
| +-- webpack-dev-server@3.11.2
| +-- webpack-merge@4.2.2
| `-- webpack@4.46.0 deduped
+-- @vue/eslint-config-airbnb@5.1.0
| +-- @vue/cli-service@4.5.6 deduped
| +-- eslint-config-airbnb-base@14.2.1
| +-- eslint-import-resolver-node@0.3.4
| +-- eslint-import-resolver-webpack@0.12.2
| +-- eslint-plugin-import@2.22.1
| `-- eslint@7.10.0 deduped
+-- @vue/eslint-config-typescript@5.1.0
| +-- @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@4.3.0 deduped invalid
| +-- @typescript-eslint/parser@4.3.0 deduped invalid
| +-- eslint-plugin-vue@7.0.0 deduped
| +-- eslint@7.10.0 deduped
| `-- vue-eslint-parser@7.6.0
+-- @vue/test-utils@1.1.0
| +-- dom-event-types@1.0.0
| +-- lodash@4.17.21
| +-- pretty@2.0.0
| +-- vue-template-compiler@2.6.12 deduped
| `-- vue@2.6.12 deduped
+-- axios@0.21.1
| `-- follow-redirects@1.13.3
+-- babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0
| `-- @babel/core@7.13.15 deduped
+-- babel-jest@26.6.3
| +-- @babel/core@7.13.15 deduped
| +-- @jest/transform@26.6.2
| +-- @jest/types@26.6.2
| +-- @types/babel__core@7.1.14
| +-- babel-plugin-istanbul@6.0.0
| +-- babel-preset-jest@26.6.2
| +-- chalk@4.1.0
| +-- graceful-fs@4.2.6
| `-- slash@3.0.0
+-- core-js@3.6.5
+-- eslint-plugin-vue@7.0.0
| +-- eslint-utils@2.1.0
| +-- eslint@7.10.0 deduped
| +-- natural-compare@1.4.0
| +-- semver@7.3.5
| `-- vue-eslint-parser@7.6.0 deduped
+-- eslint@7.10.0
| +-- @babel/code-frame@7.12.13
| +-- @eslint/eslintrc@0.1.3
| +-- ajv@6.12.6
| +-- chalk@4.1.0
| +-- cross-spawn@7.0.3
| +-- debug@4.3.1 deduped
| +-- doctrine@3.0.0
| +-- enquirer@2.3.6
| +-- eslint-scope@5.1.1
| +-- eslint-utils@2.1.0 deduped
| +-- eslint-visitor-keys@1.3.0
| +-- espree@7.3.1
| +-- esquery@1.4.0
| +-- esutils@2.0.3
| +-- file-entry-cache@5.0.1
| +-- functional-red-black-tree@1.0.1 deduped
| +-- glob-parent@5.1.2
| +-- globals@12.4.0
| +-- ignore@4.0.6
| +-- import-fresh@3.3.0
| +-- imurmurhash@0.1.4
| +-- is-glob@4.0.1
| +-- js-yaml@3.14.1
| +-- json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify@1.0.1
| +-- levn@0.4.1
| +-- lodash@4.17.21 deduped
| +-- minimatch@3.0.4
| +-- natural-compare@1.4.0 deduped
| +-- optionator@0.9.1
| +-- progress@2.0.3
| +-- regexpp@3.1.0 deduped
| +-- semver@7.3.5
| +-- strip-ansi@6.0.0
| +-- strip-json-comments@3.1.1
| +-- table@5.4.6
| +-- text-table@0.2.0
| `-- v8-compile-cache@2.3.0
+-- jest-transform-stub@2.0.0
+-- jest@26.5.3
| +-- @jest/core@26.6.3
| +-- import-local@3.0.2
| `-- jest-cli@26.6.3
+-- moment@2.29.0
+-- name-of@1.0.2
+-- sass-loader@10.0.2
| +-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY fibers@>= 3.1.0
| +-- klona@2.0.4
| +-- loader-utils@2.0.0
| +-- neo-async@2.6.2
| +-- UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY node-sass@^4.0.0
| +-- sass@1.26.11 deduped
| +-- schema-utils@2.7.1
| +-- semver@7.3.5
| `-- webpack@4.46.0 deduped
+-- sass@1.26.11
| `-- chokidar@3.5.1
+-- ts-jest@26.4.1
| +-- @types/jest@26.0.14 deduped
| +-- bs-logger@0.2.6
| +-- buffer-from@1.1.1
| +-- fast-json-stable-stringify@2.1.0
| +-- jest-util@26.6.2
| +-- jest@26.5.3 deduped
| +-- json5@2.2.0
| +-- lodash.memoize@4.1.2
| +-- make-error@1.3.6
| +-- mkdirp@1.0.4
| +-- semver@7.3.5
| +-- typescript@4.0.3 deduped
| `-- yargs-parser@20.2.7
+-- ts-nameof@5.0.0
| +-- @ts-nameof/common@4.2.1
| +-- @ts-nameof/transforms-ts@4.2.1
| +-- glob@7.1.6
| `-- typescript@4.0.3 deduped
+-- typescript@4.0.3
+-- vue-class-component@7.2.6
| `-- vue@2.6.12 deduped
+-- vue-cli-plugin-vuetify@2.0.7
| +-- null-loader@3.0.0
| +-- semver@7.3.5
| `-- shelljs@0.8.4
+-- vue-jest@3.0.7
| +-- babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0 deduped
| +-- babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs@6.26.2
| +-- chalk@2.4.2
| +-- deasync@0.1.21
| +-- extract-from-css@0.4.4
| +-- find-babel-config@1.2.0
| +-- js-beautify@1.13.5
| +-- node-cache@4.2.1
| +-- object-assign@4.1.1
| +-- source-map@0.5.7
| +-- tsconfig@7.0.0
| +-- vue-template-compiler@2.6.12 deduped
| +-- vue-template-es2015-compiler@1.9.1
| `-- vue@2.6.12 deduped
+-- vue-property-decorator@9.0.0
| +-- vue-class-component@7.2.6 deduped
| `-- vue@2.6.12 deduped
+-- vue-router@3.4.5
+-- vue-template-compiler@2.6.12
| +-- de-indent@1.0.2
| `-- he@1.2.0
+-- vue-the-mask@0.11.1
+-- vue-unique-id@3.1.1
+-- vue@2.6.12
+-- vuedraggable@2.24.3
| `-- sortablejs@1.10.2
+-- vuetify-confirm@2.0.6
| +-- vue@2.6.12 deduped
| `-- vuetify@2.3.12 deduped
+-- vuetify-loader@1.7.2
| +-- decache@4.6.0
| +-- file-loader@6.2.0
| +-- loader-utils@2.0.0
| +-- vue-template-compiler@2.6.12 deduped
| +-- vuetify@2.3.12 deduped
| `-- webpack@4.46.0 deduped
+-- vuetify@2.3.12
| `-- vue@2.6.12 deduped
+-- vuex-class@0.3.2
| +-- vue-class-component@7.2.6 deduped
| +-- vue@2.6.12 deduped
| `-- vuex@3.5.1 deduped
+-- vuex-router-sync@5.0.0
| +-- vue-router@3.4.5 deduped
| `-- vuex@3.5.1 deduped
`-- vuex@3.5.1
  `-- vue@2.6.12 deduped
```

Comment: I also found several errors identified in npm list, but I'm not sure how to fix them nor why they are causing the build to fail suddenly.

Comment: This issue started appearing on our project after an upgrade of `postcss` from `7.0.27` to  `8.2.10`.  It looks like that version included an upgrade of nanoid from 3.1.22 to 3.1.23.  https://github.com/postcss/postcss/commit/da163886b49acb8504376d3e7fd0cae3c012b3c9#diff-51e4f558fae534656963876761c95b83b6ef5da5103c4adef6768219ed76c2deL5842-R5866.  Still digging... https://github.com/ai/nanoid/commits/main

Comment: Resolved by directly editing `postcss` entry in `package-lock.json` to include `"nanoid": "^3.2.23"` under `requires` and `"nanoid": {"version": "3.1.23","resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/nanoid/-/nanoid-3.1.23.tgz","integrity": "sha512-FiB0kzdP0FFVGDKlRLEQ1BgDzU87dy5NnzjeW9YZNt+/c3+q82EQDUwniSAUxp/F0gFNI1ZhKU1FqYsMuqZVnw=="},` under `dependencies`.  Better to use `npm install` for such things, but I think our devs had edited the lock file directly as a quick fix for patching a security bug in a dependency, not yet fixed in the parent package.

Comment: I suggest using the "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolution" approach which allows you to force all resolutions of "nanoid" to a specific version; in this case "3.1.23".  This approach comes with its own set of drawbacks, but it would be more stable than directly modifying the package-lock.json (which automatically changes periodically and without prompting).  See https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.
Try checking if you're installing the node module in the correct directory, i.e. where you're writing the code for your server.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this message may be a little late, but I believe it could be beneficial for others who encounter the same problem in the future. I encountered a similar error while creating a new Angular project, but in my case, it wasn't due to version incompatibility. However, I was able to resolve it by deleting the project and recreating it. It's possible that the issue arose from an interruption or a problem with the internet connection during the initial project creation process. I suggest trying the same solution of deleting and recreating the project to see if it resolves the issue.