# NextJs Error: Cannot find module 'nanoid/non-secure'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend

im new to nextjs and my project was running fine untill i dont know what happened, just getting these errors:

```
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[8].use[2]!./styles/Navbar.css
Error: Cannot find module 'nanoid/non-secure'
Require stack:
- C:\WEBd\watchthisnext\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js
- C:\WEBd\watchthisnext\node_modules\postcss\lib\map-generator.js
- C:\WEBd\watchthisnext\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js
- C:\WEBd\watchthisnext\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js
- C:\WEBd\watchthisnext\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\config\blocks\css\index.js
- C:\WEBd\watchthisnext\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\config\index.js
- C:\WEBd\watchthisnext\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack-config.js
- C:\WEBd\watchthisnext\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\hot-reloader.js
- C:\WEBd\watchthisnext\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js
- C:\WEBd\watchthisnext\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js
- C:\WEBd\watchthisnext\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js
- C:\WEBd\watchthisnext\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js
- C:\WEBd\watchthisnext\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next
```

Please help me fix this. I have no clue why this happened.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67596861/error-cannot-find-module-nanoid-non-secure

Comment: @Andy yes i saw that, but didnt really understand + thats vue.js this is next.js , could you please help me out ?

Comment: The problem is with the postCSS package and is unrelated to either framework. Did you try the suggestion in the third comment? What version of postcss are you on?

Comment: @Andy i tried what i understood of it, but it didnt fix it